# Supplying adapter sequences for ATACseq pipeline

Tags: atac-seq

I have several `atac_seq.gz` files and I need to run the [pipeline](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/esATAC.html) with them.

I have single end `ATACseq`, so the function `atacPipe` requires me to have some kind of `adapter sequence` for it to run. What is it? Where could I get one?

> Update

I found the adapter sequences, supplied them, but it is writing me that

> Error in atacPipe(case = list("mm10", fastqInput1 = paste0(base_folder,  : 
>     adapter1 should not be NULL for single end sequencing data

```
library(esATAC)
base_folder <- "/Users/nikitavlasenko/Downloads/sams_dev/"
conclusion <- atacPipe(case=list("mm10", fastqInput1 = paste0(base_folder, "Micro_atac12.fastq.gz"),
                   adapter1 = 
"CAAGCAGAAGACGGCATACGAGATGTAGAGAGGTCTCGTGGGCTCGGAGATGT",
                   createReport = TRUE))
```

I supplied it and it is not null, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Presumably one would have to know which platform the data came from since (at least for RNA seq) there are different adapter sequence sets. [This](https://github.com/ParkerLab/bioinf525/blob/master/README.md#trimming) write up has an adapter sequence agnostic approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the function incorrectly. Here is how it worked:

```
conclusion <- atacPipe("mm10", fastqInput1 = paste0(base_folder, "Micro_atac12.fastq.gz"),
                   adapter1 = "CAAGCAGAAGACGGCATACGAGATGTAGAGAGGTCTCGTGGGCTCGGAGATGT",
                   createReport = TRUE)
```